# Unicode characters in Realm database request failure

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, unicode, realm

I am developing a mobile app. Using react native for that.
When I `react-native run-ios`, I have faced with behavior that all requests to my db that contain unicode characters in string return empty array, although I know that there are entities that satisfies that request(array of results should be non zero)
For database I am using **Realm**.

I got list of entities stored in DB, one of entity`s attribute is unicode string.
When I trying to retrieve one with certain unicode characters, like:

```
let words =
  realm.objects('Word').filtered('str CONTAINS $0', unicodeSequence)
```

I get empty array.
Although I know that it should contain entities in it (as I have used **Realm Browser** and verified that my DB contains entities that should match my request).

**Entity example:**
**/tʃʌɪnə/** and unicodeSequence is **"tʃ"**

Is any additional setup required?
What is the reason for that?

Comment: You could be more concrete.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf please see updated question